# Plesk custom 404 page not working

Tags: apache, error-handling, web, http-status-code-404, plesk

Using Plesk 11. The custom error docs is working for inside the httpdocs folder for the vhost, but it is not working for the other domains outside the vhost.

For example, my vhost is called `ns304346.ovh.net`. If I go to http://ns304346.ovh.net/thiswontwork.lol it takes me to the predefined 404 page inside the error_docs folder.

However, in this webspace I also have the domain `jaycraft.co` inside the `ns304346.ovh.net` vhost folder, but not inside the httpdocs folder. This all works great, except instead of `jaycraft.co` using the error_docs 404 page, it just goes to the index file.

For example, http://dev.jaycraft.co/thiswontwork just goes to http://dev.jaycraft.co/thiswontwork showing the index page.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your website has some internal redirecting/rewriting or rewriting in .htaccess, because the following configuration is works for me:

/var/www/vhosts/domain1.com/ <- my main domain

/var/www/vhosts/domain1.com/domain2.com/ <- additional site on same subscription

/var/www/vhosts/domain1.com/error_docs/not_found.html <- custom error document

When I open domain1.com/not_exists OR domain2.com/not_exists - it's shows 404 error with content from /var/www/vhosts/domain1.com/error_docs/not_found.html

Comment: Weird. That's the setup I'm using, but obviously not working :/

Comment: Your site is plain HTML? What happens in apache access/error logs? Logs storing in /var/www/vhosts/jaycraft.co/statistics/logs/

Comment: Not seeing anything useful in the errors logs. What exactly would I be looking for?

Comment: First of all you have to find out why this redirect http://dev.jaycraft.co/thiswontwork --> http://dev.jaycraft.co/ happens. If you don't see 404 error in log, it means that redirect happens before apache checks that /thiswontwork doesn't exists and throw 404.